# Analytic function with a zero of multiplicity 1

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f(z)$ is analytic and has exactly one zero, at $a$, inside the circle $\gamma$, and that it has multiplicity $1$. Show

$$
a = \frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_\gamma \frac{zf^{\prime}(z)}{f(z)}dz.
$$

Not sure how to approach this problem.  Would $f(z) = (z-1)^n$? looking for hints on how to do this problem.

Comment: This follows directly from a general formulation of the argument principle, have you already seen this Theorem ? Im guessing you are looking instead to prove it by a direct argument right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I present a direct argument who does not appeal to the argument principle.

Since $a$ is the only zero inside the circle $\gamma$, and that has multiplicity 1, there exist a function $g$ analytic inside $\gamma$ such that $g(z)\neq 0$ for all $z$ inside $\gamma$ and
$$
f(z)=(z-a)g(z)
$$
Then of course $f'(z)=(z-a)g'(z)+g(z)$, and thus 
$$
\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)} = \frac{z[(z-a)g'(z)+g(z)]}{(z-a)g(z)}=\frac{z(z-a)g'(z)}{(z-a)g(z)} + \frac{zg(z)}{(z-a)g(z)} = \frac{zg'(z)}{g(z)} + \frac{z}{z-a}
$$
Since $zg'(z)/g(z)$, is clearly analytic inside $\gamma$, its integral yields $0$, that is 
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)}  dz  = 0 + \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{z}{z-a} dz = a
$$
by Cauchy´s Integral Formula.